# varargs/params object[] but differentiate between actual object[] input and varargs input(s)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object, optional-parameters

In C# .NET `object` is used for multi-type arguments, allowing one to pass integers, strings, characters, etc. as possible inputs. For example:

```
// Can be called like: `F(2)`, `F("test")`, `F('a')`, etc.
void F(object arg){ ... }
```

C# .NET can also have a fixed size of optional arguments. For example:

```
// Can be called like: `F()`, `F(2)`, `F("test")`, `F('a')`, etc.
void F(object arg = null){ ... }
```

And there are also varargs, which is an undefined amount of optional arguments (which is what I've used in this answer). For example:

```
// Can be called like: `F()`, `F(2)`, `F(2, "test", 'a')`, etc.
void F(params object[] args){ ... }
```

Usually lambdas are created like this:

```
System.Func<object[], int> F f = a=>a.Length;
// A call like `f(new object[]{2, "test", 'a'))` will return 3 (size of the input array)
```

But unfortunately `System.Func` doesn't support `params` varargs, so I'll have to create a `delegate` instead:

```
delegate int F(params object[] args);
F f = a=>a.Length;
// A call like `f()` will return 0, and `f(2, "test", 'a')` will return 3
```

---

As for my question: Is there a way to know whether I've inputted an actual `object[]` instead of varargs?

So with the final lambda above, how can I let the input `f(new object[]{2,"test",'a'});` have a result of 1 instead of 3?

Kinda like how `f(new int[]{1,2,3});` will give a result of 1 because it interprets the entire integer-array as a single object. How can I have an entire object-array as single object as well using a C# .NET varargs? Is there another way to enter a varargs in C# .NET besides using `params`?

I know I can input it like `f((object)new object[]{2,"test",'a'});` to give a result of 1, but without changing the input type `f(new object[]{2,"test",'a'});` is there a way to return 1 instead of 3 (is this even possible in C# .NET)?

I tried this, but unfortunately (and as expected of course) it still returns `3`:

```
a=>((object[])(object)a).Length
```

Comment: That's not possible, but as a workaround, maybe treat the case when you received single param which is of type `object[]` in a different way?

Comment: @Evk Someone has actually found a solution for me, but thanks for the suggestion either way.

Comment: But `f(1, new object[] { 1, 2, 3 })` will again result in 4 in your solution (while 2 is expected).

Comment: @Evk Ah, indeed a good point.. That's unfortunate. Ah well, just a cast at the input in that case..